# Oracle grant select on a table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I want to grant select permission on a specific table to a remote ip address I had done it before in Mysql with this:

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@localhost identified by 'mypasswd';
```

but I can't do it in Oracle 11G

Comment: Last I checked, this isn't possible in Oracle.

Comment: Oracle uses grants that revolve around users and roles, not where they are logging in from

Answer (score 3):

You can't restrict by IP address. All you can really do is create a new user and only grant them `SELECT` on that one table.

```
create user newuser identified by 'p4ssword';
grant connect, resource to newuser;
grant select on yourtable to newuser;
```

It is actually possible to check the IP address a user is logging in from using a login trigger, and deny the login if the IP address is "wrong", but that is a different question.